# Wide chat text ends up behind the star wall in chat

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, design

I also get the same behaviour while using the browser chat on my BlackBerry. Normal chat regularly ends up behind the star wall.

Please note that we do not necessarily expect a [resolution for all cases](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2110186#2110186), but it'd be nice to have it working on mobile devices.

The problem is visible by viewing [this conversation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2110208#2110208) and having a sufficiently narrow display.

Screenshots of the problem:

[image: BlackBerry (webkit)]
[image: Chrome on Linux]
[image: Firefox on Windows]

Comment: …yeah. We get bored. And we have the collective maturity of a 13 year old.

Comment: Apropos of nothing: as an iPhone user I'm offended that *I* don't get a star wall. WTF is up with THAT? It's the CrackBerry addicts who are supposed to be third-class citizens!

Comment: set `mobile=false` in your link?

Comment: ***sigh*** that would be **EFFORT**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And throwing pennies off the space needle is dangerous, because by the time they're on the bottom, they're fast enough to dangerously hurt people.

Solution: Make the Federal Reserve add auto-expanding parachutes to pennies.

Comment: It would be so much easier to teach children the value of saving if their pennies had awesome parachutes in them.

Comment: No need http://science.howstuffworks.com/science-vs-myth/everyday-myths/threw-penny-off-the-empire-state-building.htm ... no let's treat this **serious** issue with the respect it needs, SHAME ON YOU

Comment: Using the comment system to talk over your cubicles again?  Sheesh.  Well, at least you [eat your own dog food.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food)

Comment: y'all just upset because CSS is Satan's ratty underwear and the sysadmins love exposing edge cases :-)