# Add BlackBerry browser detection to chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web, blackberry

Please add the BlackBerry phone browser to the [list of mobile browsers detected by chat.SE and redirected to the mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61755/mobile-front-end-to-the-chat).

The BB OS5+ browsers are webkit-based and actually work pretty well with even the full chat app. The main problem is that the [screen is too narrow for the chat layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108594/wide-chat-text-ends-up-behind-the-star-wall-in-chat):

[image]

Even if the browser is unsupported, it would probably benefit those (few?) users of chat.

[Various BlackBerry User-Agent strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/_uas_BlackBerry_version_.php) mention BlackBerry and Webkit.

Comment: Which BlackBerry browser?  I'd assume that BlackBerry tablets, with a 1GHz dual-core CPU, 1024x600 resolution, and full support for Flash and script, oughtn't to be redirected.  If you can provide the `User-Agent` string it would help.

Comment: User agent for the new 9810 (OS 7): `Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9810; en) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0.455 Mobile Safari/534.11+`

Comment: How can I turn on mobile chat, *manually*?

Comment: Add `?mobile=true` to the URL.

Answer (score -1):

The BlackBerry browser is unsupported (see [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)) so it's unlikely to be added if it's not 100% compatible with the Android or iOS browsers.

Comment: Actually I added those entries, it's not official.  I would expect the BB browser to be supported, given RIM's global marketshare.  But I work for RIM, so I didn't add it since that might be some sort of conflict of interest.  It would be nice if an SE employee said something officially.

Comment: @MatthewRead The fact that it's not already supported in chat, and it's not mentioned by Jeff in his reply to that question, makes me think it's unsupported. Also, I remember seeing a post where someone (Mark Gravel?) broke down browser usage on SO, and don't remember the BlackBerry browser breaking 1%. I think the post was specifically about not having a tablet version of the site, but I'm not sure.

Comment: 1% of how many visitors, though?  Jeff's answer says reasonable market share, as well, not a specific percentage of visitors.

Comment: Does detection and redirection to the mobile browser necessarily imply support? Or just an attempt to say "Hey! We've got this mobile version of chat for you!"? I was unaware of it until I searched on meta for it.